# Open an additional program with c++ on Mac [XCode]

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, shellexecute

I want to open an additional program with c++ on XCode.
It is Firefox.
But if I make

```
Shell Execute("file://localhost/Applications/Firefox.app");
```

There is an error `'ShellExecute' was not declared in this scope`
In other forum there was a clue to include windows.h and shellapi.h

```
#include <shellapi.h>
#include <windows.h>
```

but that makes other errors

```
shellapi.h: No such file or directory
windows.h: No such file or directory
```

What should I do? I want to open frefox with c++ in XCode on Mac?

Answer (score 1):

Try running this in Terminal to open Firefox:

```
open -a Firefox http://www.ibm.com
```

If that does what you want, you need to wrap it in `system()` like this:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::system("open -a Firefox");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ShellExecute()` is only available through the Windows API. You don't have a Windows system.

You can simply use the (more portable) [`system()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) function, or one of the [`exec()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/exec.html) functions available on POSIX compliant systems.

Comment: If I make `system()` only comes `sh: file://localhost/Applications/Firefox.app: No such file or directory
` But Firefox doesn't open!

Comment: You'll need that file to be an executable of course. If you want to start a local app, start firefox parameterized with that path.

Comment: I have given a false file link, it was `/Applications/Firefox.app:` but then only comes `sh: /Applications/Firefox.app: is a directory` and firefox doesn't open

Comment: @Korne127 Think it over. How would you start firefox opening that app from a command line terminal? This is what you need to specify as `system()`'s parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same with chrome and I had to set it in inverted commas:

```
int main() {
    system("open -a 'Google Chrome'");


    return 0;
}
```

with the apostrophe it worked!